# How to use the latest oe-depends-dot in Yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

From this link:

http://embeddedguruji.blogspot.com/2018/11/oe-depends-dot-in-yocto.html

It says

> To use oe-depends-dot utility you need to first generate
> recipe-depends.dot file

When I run in zeus branch of Poky, I don't get `recipe-depends.dot` file

```
$ bitbake -g core-image-minimal
```

It only creates `pn-buildlist`, `task-depends.dot`

Can we pass 'task-depends.dot' to oe-depends-dot tool?

Comment: I have the same question here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generation of `recipe-depends.dot` has been removed in Bitbake version 1.43.2 (and newer), see [commit 4c484cc01e3eee7ab2ab0359fd680b4dbd31dc30](https://github.com/openembedded/bitbake/commit/4c484cc01e3eee7ab2ab0359fd680b4dbd31dc30). This affects Yocto versions 3.0 and up.

It appears that the documentation had not been updated right away. However, the latest Bitbake documentation does not include references to the file anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will it effect also the `pn-depends.dot` file of the recipe? Meaning, if I'm running: `bitbake -g python3` for example, will it cause the `pn-depends.dot` NOT to be generated (I'm using Bitbake version 1.43.2 as you mentioed).